# Unit of a quotient ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having trouble showing whether this is true or false and why:

The class $X^3+1+(X^3+2X+1)$ is a unit in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_3[X]/(X^3+2X+1)$

I think I need to show that it has a multiplicative inverse but not sure if that's right or how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes that is the definition. Now consider what $\Bbb Z_3[X]/(X^3+2X+1)$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^3+1 = -2x$ mod $x^3+2x+1$ and $1 = -x^3-2x$ mod $x^3+2x+1$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is the ground ring we have $-2x = x$ and $1 = 2x^3+x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$. Therefore $1 = x(2x^2+x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$. Hence $(x^3+1)^{-1}= 2x^2+x$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is what you need to show.

Hint: Note that $[X^3 + 1] = [X]$ (using brackets to denote residue classes), and also $$[1] = [2X^3 + X] = [X][2X^2 + 1] = [X^3 + 1][2X^2 + 1].$$ Therefore...

Comment: How did you get that $[X^3+1]=[X]$?

Comment: Oh nevemind I see that now.

Comment: $X^3 + 2X + 1$ is zero in your ring so $X^3 + 1$ is $-2X$ which is the same as $X$ because $3 = 0$.